# Bash - iterate over a union of two (disjoint) arrays

Tags: bash, solaris, opensolaris

I am writing a bash script (for an Open Solaris 11 machine).

I have declared two arrays in the following way:

```
rpool_fs=(
  "rpool"
  "rpool/ROOT"
  "rpool/ROOT/solaris"
  "rpool/export"
);

shares_fs=(
  "shares"
  "shares/svn"
);
```

I am able to iterate over the rpool_fs array in the following way:

```
for i in "${rpool_fs[@]}"
do
  echo $i
done
```

**I would now need to iterate over the union of the rpool_fs and shares_fs arrays.** Note that the arrays are disjoint, e.g. I do in fact only need to iterate over a concatention of them. How do I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just put one after the other:

```
for i in "${rpool_fs[@]}" "${shares_fs[@]}"
do
  echo $i
done
```